# Can anyone explain the concept of "being-thus"?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, quantum-physics, quantum-interpretations

I was reading a letter from Einstein to Max Born that says something like this:

> It is further characteristic of these physical objects that they
>   are thought of as arranged in a space-time continuum. An essential aspect of this arrangement of things in physics
>   is that they lay claim, at a certain time, to an existence independent of one another, provided these objects ‘are
>   situated in different parts of space.’ Unless one makes this kind of assumption about the independence of the
>   existence (the ‘**being-thus**’) of objects which are far apart from one another in space—which stems in the first
>   place from everyday thinking—physical thinking in the familiar sense would not be possible.

and then I searched for this word, that is ‘being-thus’, and found some other sources:

> Einstein viewed the Copenhagen interpretation as 'a gentle pillow for the true
>   believer.' 1° For Einstein, a physical system has a 'being-thus,' a 'real state' that is
>   independent of other systems or the means of observation (see the quotations in section
>   1.1 and section 6.1). He argued that realism about physical systems in this sense is
>   incompatible with the assumption that the state descriptions of quantum mechanics
>   are complete.
>   *Interpreting the Quantum World
>   By Jeffrey Bub*

and:

> Being-thus is not a substance of which thus would express
>   .a. determination or a qualification. Being is not a presupposition that is before
>   or after its qualities. Being that is irreparably thus is .its thus; it is only
>   its mode of being. {The thus is not an essence that determines an existence,
>   .but it finds its essence in its own being-thus, in its being its own determination.) 
>   *The Coming Community
>   By Giorgio Agamben*

Now, this is really confusing. Can anyone first explain this term (like explaining how this term is constructed (it's origins) or explain it in a Synonym way) and not the concept and then explain this concept in a simpler way. I should note that I have not much knowledge in this area. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The more commonly used term for Einstein's "being-thus" is ["element of reality"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-epr/#ArguText) that appears in the EPR paradox. Einstein's elements of reality are supposed to be localized and allow no action at a distance, i.e. their properties are independently determinate when they are far apart. This is inconsistent with the non-local collapse of the wave function, assuming that the wave function is a complete description of a quantum system, as the Copenhagen interpretation holds.

Comment: Having being-thus seems to mean: having a determinate and independent state. Independent, that is, of the  simultaneous states of non adjacent bodies or fields.